# Using multiple Queues instead of one PriorityQueue

Tags: java

currently I'm using a PriorityBlockingQueue for my producer-consumer-system but since I have only 3 different priorities I thought about using 3 different BlockingQueues instead.

This way no work has to be done when inserting elements.

Might this approach be more effective or not and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, this way is more effective as it has `O(1)` insertion time vs `O(log N)` insertion time of a priority queue.

It follows the [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) idea in which you count the number of each element and output them accordingly. Counting sort also uses the fact that all input elements fall into a narrow range of values.